# irrlicht for android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was  just wondering after noticing that moblox was.built with irrlicht if there is an android port of it?  Or did the dev make his own port from scratch?

From my research I noticed a port project on github but it seems far from ready.-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a developper of [Iopixel](http://www.iopixel.com) (formely Ellismarkov). For moblox, we use my own port of [Irrlicht for Android](http://gitorious.org/irrlichtandroid/irrlichtandroid) for code base but we rewrite parts of Irrlicht for better performance and better iOS/Android compatibility:

- OpenGL ES Save/Load contexts
- Texture management
- many changes in driver API with two drivers

  - OpenGL 3.x for Desktop (used for tests)
  - OpenGL ES 2.x (Android, iOS)

I tried to backport modifications but it is now two distincts Pipelines. My port of Irrlicht is not complete but usable. Other developers have used it on market.

As i said to Irrlicht developers, it will be better to use NativeActivity for an official port (available with 2.3 devices).

Comment: Wow awesome.  Thanks. Any chance you will make your port public?

Comment: No it's not mine but Iopixel. I'm working on OpenGL ES 2.x tutorial and will probably release a mobile 3d engine with it.

Comment: Sounds awsome would love to know where to find it when its ready